Is $\underbrace{nn\cdots n}_{n\text{ times}}\cdots333221$ ever a prime number?
Is $\underbrace{nn\cdots n}_{n\text{  times}}\cdots333221$ ever a prime number?
This question is inspired from this comment.
I have an idea that if $n\equiv0,1,4,8\pmod{9}$, then the sum of digits of $\underbrace{nn\cdots n}_{n\text{  times}}\cdots333221$ will be divisible by $3$.
Aside from that, I did also check all values of $n$ up to $15000$, and no number listed there is a prime number.

$p=2222333221$ is prime. The digit sum is not divisible by $3$, by the way.

@DietrichBurde I think the OP's sequence goes $1, 221, 333221, 4444333221, 555554444333221, \ldots$.

@RobertIsrael Yes.

Ah, sorry.......

So when $n=10$ is the number $101010101010101010109999999\ldots333221$? [I intended to write $"10"$ a total of $10$ times]

Heuristically, a number with $d$ digits has probability on the order of $1/d$ to be prime.  In this sequence, the number of digits increases rapidly enough that the expected number of primes to be found should be finite, and once the first few thousand members of the sequence have been found to be composite the probability of finding a prime gets quite small.  Of course, that is not a proof.

Did you really check $n$ up to $15,000$? If so, this would require running primality tests on numbers up to $$\sum _{k=1}^9 k+2 \sum _{k=10}^{99} k+3 \sum _{k=100}^{999} k+4 \sum _{k=1000}^{9999} k+5 \sum _{k=10000}^{15000} k=512,038,005$$ digits long.

@Stevenclark Yes.

The largest known prime number is only $24,862,048$ digits when written in base $10$.

fun question +1

What did you use to check primality up to such huge numbers?

Could you please explain what checks exactly you did for values of $n$ up to 15000.  On the one hand you seem to say you did primality tests.  On the other hand that seems very implausible for such large numbers.  It is rather unsatisfactory to leave the question as is without clarifying this point.

@AdamBailey Pari GP and Phyton.
